# ENV Variables and Config.env

Tags: php

How can I setup Config.env with plain php? What I did so far, is created config.env, passed some infos there. But as soon as I load page where I need to use those infos, it prints me out the whole content of config.env.

Config.env

```
PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID = TEST
PAYPAL_SECRET = TEST
PAYPAL_BASE_URL = https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.co
```

PayPal.php

```
require '../config.env';

class PayPal{
 //URL
 CURLOPT_URL => getenv("PAYPAL_BASE_URL") . '/v1/oauth2/token',
}
```

But like I said, it prints out everywhere the content of Config.env 
Any idea?

Comment: There is no native `config.env` concept in PHP that, when loaded, would set `$_ENV` variables. Also, we have no idea what you've put into your `config.env` file. I'm guessing it's simply output as a string and the file has no PHP in it. If all you need is setting curl options, you don't need to deal with ENV at all. Just set constants or have a class that takes the variables as arguments, e.g. into your `PayPal` class constructor.

Answer (score 0):

you need to creat class to handle this
please check the following article for creating your own .env file & method

https://dev.to/fadymr/php-create-your-own-php-dotenv-3k2i

for a simpler solution you can use `define()` for defining you constants you need to put them in PHP file ex:`config.php`  and use every where

with configs
like that

```
if (!defined('PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID')) define('PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID', 'TEST');
if (!defined('PAYPAL_SECRET')) define('PAYPAL_SECRET', 'TEST');
if (!defined('PAYPAL_BASE_URL')) define('PAYPAL_BASE_URL', 'https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.co');
```

and at PayPal.php

````
require '../config.php';

class PayPal{
 //URL
 CURLOPT_URL => PAYPAL_BASE_URL . '/v1/oauth2/token',
}```
````

Comment: Like I said, I want to work only with Plain PHP (Because I am beginner). And what you've send is dotenv (extension)

Comment: these articles learn you how to create your own getenv() method, 
i updated my answer for a simpler solution, kindly check